# Regex: How to match capitalised words that include a special character

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to put together a regex pattern in python that would match words that begin with a capital letter, but also contain an apostrophe within them

words such as: **She's**, **Albert's** and **Haven't**

but exclude others such as 'She'

So far I've only managed to match the capitalised words in the text using:

```
match = r'(\b[A-Z].*?\b)'
output = re.findall(match, text)
print(output)
```

thanks :)

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-z]*'[a-z]+", text)` or if the words may be in mixed case, `re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][A-Za-z]*'[A-Za-z]+", text)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex: `\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]+\b`

Code:

```
print(re.findall(r"\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]+", text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will be

```
regex_pattern = r"[A-Z]\w*?'\w*" 
# Ensure that you use double quotes for the raw string, not single quotes, otherwise the apostrophe will not match.
```

To match objects, you can either use re.findall() or re.match().group(), as needed.

```
re.findall(regex_pattern,"She's she she's")
["She's"]
```